# Is there software/program that can bulk symlink a bunch of files? What about a shell script?

Tags: macos, symbolic-link

I have like a couple hundred different files I want to symlink, is there any program where I can select all the files I want to symlink (keeping the same file name in the symlink destination) and then choose where they go. They would all get symlinked  in the same directory. Im using Mac OS X 10.9.1. If there is no software to do this, could I create a shell script that'll symlink files that contain a certain keyword in the file name? Say I have:

```
/orginal

fileDis
fileDat
thing1
thing2
```

And I want to symlink all files with the word "file" in the name to a directory, keeping there original filename so the result would be:

```
/symlinks

fileDis
fileDat
```

Tried this like suggested:

```
cd /symlinks 

for a in /original/*file* ; do ln -s $a . ; done
```

And ended up with just having

```
*File*
```

show up in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the /symlinks directory:

```
for a in /original/file* ; do ln -s $a . ; done
```

(You might want `/original/*file*/` if you also want to symlink '`somefile`')

Comment: Useless Use of `for` Alert!  (-:

Comment: tried this but didnt seem to work. See my updated question